# Angular httpBackend crashing browser

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, restangular

When using Jasmine and Angular (1.4.7) with Restangular (1.4.0), httpBackend and angular-mocks (1.4.7), Chrome and PhantomJS both crash when encountering the following line:

```
httpBackend.whenGET('/something').respond(200);
```

If I get rid of it entirely, as below, I get the following error:

```
//httpBackend.whenGET('/something').respond(200);
scope.doSomething();  // will invoke a GET to /keepAlive
httpBackend.expectGET("/something").respond(200);
httpBackend.flush();
```

**Error: Unexpected request: GET /something
No more request expected**

The code that it is testing is:

```
$scope.doSomething = function () {
    Restangular.one('something').get();
};
```

I've tried everything I can think of.  I'm down to the idea that this is just a bug in Karma/Jasmine/Restangular but I don't know how to work around it.

One thing worth noting is that httpBackend and Restangular disagree about the URL.  Restangular adds the `/` to `/something`.  httpBackend doesn't.  This is why they don't match.

Things I've tried that didn't work:

- Calling /something from Restangular.  **Says unexpected GET //something
  (two slashes)**
- Using /something/another instead of a single root level
  directory.  **No difference.**
- using $http instead of Restangular.  **No difference.**

Comment: My guess is that your code has an infinite loop. Can you isolate the code so we could recreate the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this a while ago.  What happened is that the $httpBackend test caused a route change. That route change caused an event to fire and got us stuck in a loop.

However, this only happened when testing with $httpBackend.  In the real world, this infinite loop didn't happen.

There were two solutions:

1. redefine $location.go in your beforeEach() so that your testing will not
   actually cause a redirect  -or -
2. capture the event somehow and squash it, or just change your code to
   not trigger it